# Can I remove from a list while iterating it?

Tags: java

I have this code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < oldCars.size(); ++i)
    {
        if(oldCars.get(i).getVelocity().length() > 0.0f)
        {
            oldCars.get(i).update(timeStep);
        }
        else
        {
            oldCars.remove(i);
        }
    }
```

It seems to work fine, but will it work in all conditions?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to remove when iterating, start from the end :

```
for(int i = oldCars.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if(oldCars.get(i).getVelocity().length() > 0.0f)
    {
        oldCars.get(i).update(timeStep);
    }
    else
    {
        oldCars.remove(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess it won't update all entries.

If you remove an entry your `i` index goes up, however the next item would have the current `i` value as well.

```
oldcar 1
oldcar 2
oldcar 3
```

Remove "oldcar 1" i will be 1 and the next entry you check is "oldcar 3" instead of "oldcar 2".

Comment: you could mention to add `i--;` when removing to get desired behaviour.

Comment: that's why I wrote **add `i--;` when removing** ;) OP is either updating or removing.

Answer (score 2):

```
   Iterator<T> it = oldCars.iterator();

    while (it.hasNext()) {
        T oldCar = it.next();
        if (oldCar.getVelocity().length() > 0.0f) {
            oldCar.update(timeStep);
        } else {
            it.remove();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use your method, but modify it slightly. When you remove an item from the list, the next item will get jumped over, so you will have to decrement `i` each time you remove an item. So, you would have the following:

```
for(int i = 0; i < oldCars.size(); ++i)
{
    if(oldCars.get(i).getVelocity().length() > 0.0f)
    {
        oldCars.get(i).update(timeStep);
    }
    else
    {
        oldCars.remove(i--);
    }
}
```